# What does "Espresso yourself! Ad gets latte love" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, sentence-meaning

I know Starbucks UK launched a new campaign to promote acceptance of sex change in young teens by encouraging them to give baristas their “new” name when they purchase coffee so it can be “called out” in the store.

Regarding this, Metro.News said “Espresso yourself! Ad gets latte love.”
What does this mean?
Is that a figurative expression?
(I thought maybe "espresso yourself" intends to mean "express yourself.")

Please help me understand it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's an unsubtle play on words. "Espresso yourself" is, indeed, used to mean "express yourself" and "ad gets latte love" is similarly used to mean "advertisment gets a lot of love".

Using the names of different types of coffee is a joke on Starbucks's core business and "gets a lot of love" is a way of saying that the Starbucks campaign gets a high approval rating. There is nothing else to understand.

Comment: On the other hand, the campaign gives Starbucks critics a grande opportunity to venti their spleen.